# What are the origins of ド when used as emphasis, and is it always negative?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, politeness

Sometimes I've seen ド as a prefix that adds emphasis to words. So saying someone is ドバカ is saying that they are much more stupid than just バカ.

I'm wondering what the origin of ド in this context is. Does it come from 度 【ど】("degree"), as in, "the degree of X is higher"?

Also, is it always negative? I usually see it attached to negative terms, but I don't know if it's exclusively negative.

Lastly, is it impolite?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In present Japanese, the usage is not limited to negative terms

> ど真ん中 'right in the middle', 'bingo!'
>   ど根性 'strong guts'

but does not seem to be productive either (i.e., usage is limited). When it is used with a negative term, that is surely impolite, but the words listed above are not particularly impolite.

`ど` seems to have derived from the 18th century form `どう`, whose meaning is not clear. There is another descendant form `どん`, which developed mainly in the context of kabuki (歌舞伎), and seems to be used only for negative terms.

> どん尻
>   どんケツ
>   どん引き [Recent slang]

Here are some discussions on other sites:

- http://kotobakai.seesaa.net/article/8237957.html
- http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nobita720/20110702

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if it's always from the kanji 度 or not.  However, of the few examples I found, there was `ど真ん中` (straight down the middle), so there is at least one situation where it's not negative.

And here's [the definition from 大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154704/m0u/):

> ## ど
>
> ```
> 〘接頭〙名詞や形容詞に付く。
> １ まさにそれに相当するものであることを強調する。「—真ん中」「—ぎつい」
> ２ ののしり卑しめる意をより強く表す。「—けち」「—下手」
> ```

So based on this, I would say that words themselves are not impolite, just maybe *how* you use it.

A common one I use is `度忘れする` (this one I know for sure uses 度) meaning "to slip your mind" or "momentarily cannot recall".  I don't see any way this in itself could be impolite.

Comment: Re: 度忘れ, Shogakukan states: （「どうわすれ（胴忘）」の変化で、「度」は当て字） (A shift from *dōwasure* (胴忘), with 度 as ateji).  Then, under 胴忘, we see: （「どう」は、ののしる意の接頭語を自嘲の意に転用したものという。「胴」は当て字） (The *dō* is apparently a pejorative prefix used to indicate self-deprecation. The 胴 is ateji).  It might be useful to compare this Japanese *dō* and English pejoratives *d'oh!* or *dur*.  I suspect this pejorative *dō* is cognate with both the Kabuki *don* and sense 2 of *do* from 大辞泉 above, and that the pejorative *dō, don, do* merged with a different *do* indicating emphasis as in sense 1 above.