# Where does the ド in ド素人 come from?

Tags: etymology

素人 means beginner.
ド素人 means total beginner.

`ド` means "very", "total". Any idea where does this word come from etymologically? It is sometimes also written in hiragana.

Are there other current expressions that use `ド` in a similar way?

Comment: [Dreadnought?!](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q133841243)

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/what-are-the-origins-of-%E3%83%89-when-used-as-emphasis-and-is-it-always-negative)

Comment: @istrasci. How are links embedded in comments? I tried using the same format for answers but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Flaw `[link text](url)`. See also http://japanese.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @Flaw:  Just click the **help** link right under the "Add Comment" button when you're typing a comment.

Comment: @PaulRichter As for the Dreadnought: there's an informal expression "ド級"/"弩級" used to express extraordinary massiveness, which actually came from that Dreadnought. E.g.. [重さ3トンで32億画素という超ド級カメラ](http://gigazine.net/news/20150116-lsst-largest-camera/). 広辞苑 states that the "ど" as in "ド素人" originated in 近世 (when used in Japanese history, it's roughly 1600-1850), so these are different "ド". Still interesting, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ど突く, ドスケベ, どあほ, ドM, ドS, どえらい, どぶす, ど近眼... sure there are many more

Please note that some of these are quite rude and offensive. Please use with caution.

Not sure about the etymology, but I have the impression that they tend to be used more in Kansai-ben.

Comment: あはは。悪い言葉ばっかりね～　あ、あたし関西人

Comment: I share the same impression too! But unless non-関西人 can confirm that they seldom use ど…

Comment: So we don't really know where it comes from? I just saw this in Harry Potter 2, which doesn't seem to have a rude/offensive tone implied: "ダンブルドアが次の言葉を話し出す前に、バーンとどえらい音をたてて扉が勢いよく開き、ハグリッドが飛び込んできた。"

Comment: @comeauch: dainichi wrote than "some" are rude/offensive. Some others are not, for instance ど真ん中.

Answer (score 3):

どぎつい, ど真ん中 and ド変態{へんたい} come to mind as similar expressions.

I don't know where this use of ド came from. Maybe from the phrase 度{ど}が過ぎる.

Comment: OMG ド変態！I've never heard that word but it's like a total pervert? Lol

Comment: どん百姓 is another one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not "etymology" per se, but the Tokyo dialect has borrowed "ど" from Kansai-ben.  I don't have a solid reference to back up this claim, but I remember reading that in books written by scholars.  Also there is a Wikipedia entry about Kansai-ben (cited below) and its vocabulary section includes this very "ど".

"ど" is still informal in the Tokyo dialect and tends to be avoided in formal speech and writing in my experience (living in the Tokyo area for a long time). Some traditionalists disdain it as vulgar because there are good traditional alternatives.  For example, Tokyoites used to say まん真ん中 instead of ど真ん中 (dead center, right in the middle, etc.) but the latter is becoming more and more common now.  To Tokyoites' ear today, まん真ん中 sounds perfectly fine and a bit more elegant than ど真ん中, but it lacks the forcefulness and vividness of the latter.  You can say the same for other words qualified by "ど".

[近畿方言 from Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BF%91%E7%95%BF%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)