# と prefixing a verb?

Tags: verbs, etymology, prefixes

I sometimes see と apparently being used as a verb prefix, e.g.:

> もう、とぼけないでよ。
>
> Stop joking around.

Can somebody explain what the と does in cases like this?

Comment: But とぼける is a verb.

Comment: @oals Yes, and と is a prefix attached to the base ぼける.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ordinary Japanese learner should probably memorize とぼける and ぼける as two totally different verbs.

- とぼける: to play dumb; to feign ignorance; to play innocent
- ぼける: to play stupid (as a joke); to develop dementia

They seem to be etymologically related, but even native speakers do not regard this と as a prefix.

Etymologically, according to [this article](http://gogen-allguide.com/to/tobokeru.html) and [this question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1413926839), this と seems to be a rare prefix that somehow emphasizes the original verb. Unfortunately I cannot think of another example of と in this sense. But [ど/ド](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4435/5010) is a common prefix used to emphasize the following word.

Comment: 「とまどう」がありますね。あと「とぎれる」「とだえる」も同じだという説もあります。

Comment: @broccoliforest おお、ありがとうございます。言われないとまったく気づきませんが…(^^;)