# What is the meaning of ド in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning

What is the meaning of ド in this sentence?

> 抜け駆けかド畜生

Contex: some guys take the lead and the character don't realize it.

It used the same way as [this ド](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/what-are-the-origins-of-%E3%83%89-when-used-as-emphasis-and-is-it-always-negative) and modifies 畜生?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you have anything else to ask?

Comment: Nop, that's all.